# Console output: org.springframework.web.servlet.PageNotFound noHandlerFound HTTP status 404 : The requested resource is not available

Tags: java, spring-mvc, tomcat

I have seen similar question asked before. I tried solutions offered to them but still facing the same problem. 
I am trying to run simple hello world spring mvc application.
The output I am getting is [HTTP Status 404](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lZIl1.png)

In console,
[I can see following message.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gv3Vi.png)

[This is my project structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eH0Oa.png)

Following are the code files.

web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" 
xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee 
http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" version="3.0">
<display-name>HelloWorldApplication</display-name>
<welcome-file-list>
<welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>

<servlet>
    <servlet-name>HelloWorld</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>
        org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet
    </servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>HelloWorld</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/welcome.jsp</url-pattern>
    <url-pattern>/index.jsp</url-pattern>
    <url-pattern>/welcome.html</url-pattern>
    <url-pattern>*.html</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

</web-app>
```

HelloWorld-servlet.xml

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc" xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans     
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd">

<context:component-scan base-package="com.HelloWorld.controller" />

<bean id="viewResolver"
    class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.UrlBasedViewResolver">
    <property name="viewClass"
        value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView" />
    <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/" />
    <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
</bean>
```

HelloWorldMain.java

```
package com.HelloWorld.controller;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;

/*
 * author: Siddhesh Jethe
 * 
 */

@Controller
public class HelloWorldMain {

@RequestMapping("/welcome")
public ModelAndView helloWorld() {

    String message = "<br><div style='text-align:center;'>"
            + "<h3>********** Hello World </h3> Welcome**********</div><br><br>";
    return new ModelAndView("welcome", "message", message);
}
}
```

index.jsp

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Test project</title>
<style type="text/css">

</style>
</head>
<body>
    <br>
    <div style="text-align:center">
        <h2>
            test<br> <br>
        </h2>
        <h3>
            <a href="welcome.html">Click here to See Welcome Message... </a>
        </h3>
    </div>
 </body>
 </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

What Http request do you see in the Network tab in Devtools of the browser?
Does that match with your controller?
Based on your configuration, the URL `http://<servername>:<port>/HelloWorld/welcome` should be hit for your welcome.jsp to be rendered.

Comment: Apology for late reply.  I tried what you suggested. i.e. http://localhost:8080/HelloWorld/welcome.    But it didnt work. Still facing the same issue.

Comment: I tried with http://localhost:8080/HelloWorld/welcome.jsp.  . It is working now. But I do have to add "welcome.jsp" in front of "http://localhost:8080/HelloWorld/" every time I running the application. Any way I can directly get the output screen without having to add "welcome.jsp" manually . Thank you for your previous solution.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve the problem. I just removed all the url patterns I have written in web.xml and added only one as "/" . And it worked.